# Developing a Custom Option page under the Settings menu

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I am new in the amazing world of wordpress
I am now working on my first wordpress plugin.
I have added shortcodes and they work fine.
Then, for learning purpose, I wanted to add a plugin option page under the settings menu.
I want the page to have the following form:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <h2>My Plugin Page</h2>
    <p>My first wordpress plugin<br/>Here is the
form:</p>

    <form method="post">
 <input name="write" size="50" /><br/>
 <input name="submit" type="submit" />
 </form>

 <?php
 if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) die();
 $typed = $_POST['write'];
 print "You wrote ".$typed ;
 ?>
 </div>
```

For now I just need the page to appear in the menu. I googled about it, so many things came up and i don't understand which one is wich.
So far my code is:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu' , 'plugin_op_page' );
function plugin_op_page() {
add_options_page( 'Type Here' , 'Type Here' , '
manage_options' , 'myplugin' , 'write_sample' );
 }
function write_sample() {
?>
 <div>
//above mentioned form
 </div>
<?php
   } 
?>
```

But anything doesn't shows up in the settings menu, I guess i am missing something like "admin_init" ?
Please Help

Comment: try function add_submenu_page( 'options-general.php',...);

Comment: a little more, pease??
how should I use this? :(

Comment: your code works as is on a fresh wp install

Comment: The problem seems to be the line break before `manage_options`. Put the `add_options_page` args all on one line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the right syntax:

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'plugin_op_page');
function plugin_op_page() {
    add_menu_page('Page name', 'Page name', 'administrator', 'page-slug', 'new_settings_page','dashicons-admin-generic');
}
function new_settings_page() {
    echo 'The page is live!';
}
```

Let me know if it works!

Comment: Thanks!!!!!! :D
it works perfect, 
but 1 problem, when I install the plugin, it says :

    The plugin generated 1 characters of unexpected
    output during activation. If you notice “headers
    already sent” messages, problems with
    syndication feeds or other issues, try
    deactivating or removing this plugin.
any idea why? :(
but after that, everything works fine.
@diggy, Yap I think so, the line break was the problem, when I copied the code provided by Yavor,  It didn't work at first, then I removed the line break and it was perfect. Thanks :)

Comment: You probably have a space before the first <?php tag in your plugin or you are outputting something ele when the plugin's main file it executed. You should only be outputting data inside the options page function. Did you find anything like this? Otherwise it's possible you have a hidden BOM character, read about it here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

Comment: Everything is ok now
Thanks!!! :D
I had to delete all the unnecessary spaces, and now it works fine.
The wordpress team also accepted my little effort.
Thanks for the answer, it was really helpfull.